# How to sort an array with symbol?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this with decimal values

`["$79.34", "$99.23", "$149", "$139.34", "$379", "$199.00", "$5", "$9", "$14", "$39", "$59", "$24", "$29", "$189", "$10,$20", "$500", "$1", "$4", "$8.66", "$2", "$19", "$18", "$11", "$15", "$40", "$89", "$100", "$400.15", "$30,$119", "$15,$30"]`

For my store and I can't figure out how to use javascript to sort them ? The `$` (or any symbol for that matter) seems to be causing issues for me ?

How can I solve this ?

Comment: What about the values where there seem to be two separate amounts within the same string, such as the last two (among others): `"$30,$119", "$15,$30"` is that a typo, or deliberate?

Comment: ah thats intentional - the results can be like that ?

Comment: That significantly complicates the problem.

Comment: from your data, which is greater: "$10,$20" or "$30,$119"?  "$15,$30" or "$40". why?

Comment: How is `$79.34` an integer value?

Comment: "I have an array like this with decimal values...." No. No, you do not.

Comment: What does that mean then? How does "$30,$119" compare with "$15" or "$199"

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: How is `$30,$119` a decimal value?

Comment: it is not, but IIRC, OP wants to sanitize the data, then sort them as if they were decimals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var prices = [...]
prices.sort(function(a,b) { return (a.substring(1)) - (b.substring(1)); })
```

would do the trick.

Comment: Only problem with this is it doesn't handle the "$10,$20" case, though it would be very odd indeed to have that as data

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I wrote a [JSFiddle to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/qVbz5/29/)

```
function sortPrices(priceStrings) 
{
    //first sanitize the data
    for (var i = 0; i < priceStrings.length; i++) 
    {
        if (priceStrings[i].toString().search(",") != -1) 
        {
            var splits = priceStrings[i].toString().split(",");
            priceStrings.splice(i, 1)
            priceStrings = priceStrings.concat(splits);
            i--;
        }
    }
    var prices = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < priceStrings.length; i++) 
    {
        priceStrings[i] = priceStrings[i].toString().replace("$", "");
        prices.push(parseFloat(priceStrings[i]));
    }

    prices.sort(function(a,b){return a - b});

    return prices;
}​
```